# Dynamically connecting C++ methods with dynamic cast if required

Tags: c++

I'm searching a way to avoid systematic dynamic cast in the following problem.

I have Action objects and Message objects. Action objects have methods that emits messages, and other methods that accept messages. There are of course derived Action classes and Messages classes. The objects and their methods are connected dynamically at run time by string identification based on a configuration file defining the network of interconnected objects.

This is equivalent to a signal slot system with a strong constrain on the number and type of the arguments. All signals emit a message derived of the class Message and all slots accept a message derived from the class Message.

Connections are NxN. Thus signals are multicast and slots can accept signals from multiple sources.

The current implementation is to use a Link class instantiating the connection between a signal and a slot. The signals and slots are functor member variables. Each Action object has a two maps. One from string name to signal and one from string name to slot. There is also a global map of Action names to instance. The benefit of keeping track of links in the target Action (slots) is to properly disconnect all links when the instance is destroyed.

In a first pass all Action instances defined in the configuration file are instantiated, In a second pass links are instantiated connecting signals to slots.

The question is how would you implement this so that a message type matching check is only performed when the link is instantiated and so that a dynamic cast is only performed if required.

For instance if we have the message base class M and a subclass M1 of M and a subclass M2 of M1, a link from signal(M2) to slot(M1) or slot(M) would not perform a dynamic cast, and a link from signal(M1) or signal(M) to slot(M2) would perform a dynamic cast. The slot method is only called is the dynamic cast succeeds (doesn't return nullptr).

An implementation where a dynamic cast is performed at each call is trivial. I seek a solution to avoid this if possible.

My current understanding is that I can't use boost::signals because of the dynamic binding.

Comment: May I ask why you absolutely want to get rid of the `dynamic_cast<>`s ?

Comment: I would guess it is a performance thing.  However, I am having a little difficulty in seeing why it is required anyway.  Could you provide a code sample to show what you mean?

Comment: For this use-case it sounds like you should be using virtual functions not dynamic casts.

Comment: @ereOn as Stefan wrote it is for performance. Though I didn't measure the overhead. Here is an example: if the slot method accepts messages of class M2 and the signal may emit messages of type M1 or M then a dynamic cast is required because the emitted signal could be an instance of type M2. A use case is for an Action object behaving as a message relay and counting messages traversing it. It would have a slot(M) and signal(M). Though it could be inserted in an link connecting an signal(M2) and slot(M2) where M2 messages are flowing. A dynamic cast to M2 is thus required.

Comment: @ben, could you develop please ? I don't see how virtual methods could help me here.

Comment: @chmike: Shouldn't you profile your code **first** then eventually optimize things ? It seems to me that your are getting rid of all the  `dynamic_cast`s to solve a problem that may not even exist. Looks like premature optimization to me.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? I am struggling to think of a problem to which this might be a solution.

Comment: @ereOn, you are right. The dynamic cast solution is already working. So I'm in the optimization process. I should be able to get rid of it and I'm asking if it is possible and how to do it.

Comment: @Ben Look at Qt's Phonon for an equivalent system : http://qt.developpez.com/doc/4.7/phonon-overview/#phonon-overview. It is a system by witch we can interconnect data processing boxes. Phonon is for signal processing. My application is for different application but uses the same model. Data transferred between processing boxes (Actions) are Messages. I plan to add serialization and transmission between processes and computers so that the processing network can span over multiple computers.

Comment: The slot should give access to a function created with bind and calling the object's method. The problem is that this function has a parameter which will be different for each method. Thus the function pointer can't be stored in a member variable of the slot class.

Comment: So are you doing media encoding and decoding then?

Comment: No. It was just an example. I'm doing generic data processing. The system is designed so that data will flows through data processing objects. The network of objects will be defined by program configuration. There might also be many kinds of data. Data processing objects are called Action and data objects Message. I can't tell the real application.

Comment: For "Generic data processing" I recommend using a turing-complete "high level language" in conjunction with a "compiler" or "interpreter". You can then configure the system to process different data in different ways by writing schedules or "programs" of actions to be done for each process, which do the specific data processing you are actually wanting to do in each case....  This has the advantage that you can use completely different paradigms for different processes rather than be tied into a particular paradigm. In the meantime, **avoid premature optimisation**.

Comment: I've solved my problem! The solution is clean and concise. I'll present it's core as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem. Here is the code which is nicely concise.
The signal is also a template class which simply defines the message types it may emit. 
Thus, when connecting the signal with a slot, the Link constructor can check the polymorphic compatibility of the message type emitted by the signal and the message type accepted by the slot. It then copies the appropriate function pointer whether a dynamic cast is required or not. What is not shown here is the Type class and how it is used to check message type compatibility.

The answer was how to define the two slot functions and their function pointers.

Here is an example how the slots would be defined in a class:

```
class MyAction : public Action
{
public:
    //! Define shared pointer on object
    typedef std::shared_ptr<MyAction> Ptr;

    //! Constructor
    MyAction( const std::string& name )
        : Action(name),
          m_slotMsgM( this ),
          m_slotMsgA( this ),
          m_slotMsgB( this )
    {
    }

    //! Register the slots with their name for dynamic linking
    void configure()
    {
        add("processMsgM", &m_slotMsgM );
        add("processMsgA", &m_slotMsgA );
        add("processMsgB", &m_slotMsgB );
    }

    //! Slot method 
    void processMsgM( Message::Ptr msg, Link * link = nullptr )
    {
        cout << "MyAction::processMsgM: Msg " << msg->type().name() << endl;
    }

    //! Slot method 
    void processMsgA( MsgA::Ptr msg, Link * link = nullptr )
    {
        cout << "MyAction::processMsgA: Msg " << msg->type().name() << endl;
    }

    //! Slot method 
    void processMsgB( MsgB::Ptr msg, Link * link = nullptr )
    {
        cout << "MyAction::processMsgB: Msg " << msg->type().name() << endl;
    }

protected:
    //! Define slots
    SlotT<MyAction, Message, &MyAction::processMsgM> m_slotMsgM;
    SlotT<MyAction, MsgA, &MyAction::processMsgA> m_slotMsgA;
    SlotT<MyAction, MsgB, &MyAction::processMsgB> m_slotMsgB;
};
```

Here is the Slot and SlotT classes definition.

```
class Link;
typedef std::set<Link*> LinkSet;

//! Base class for Slot template class
class Slot
{
    friend class Link;
public:
    //! Slot function pointer
    typedef std::function<void ( Message::Ptr, Link* )> Function;

    //! Disconnect all links
    ~Slot();

    //! Return the type of message accepted by this Slot function
    const TypeDef& messageType() const { return m_msgType; }

    //! Return slot function applying a dynamic cast on the message pointer
    Function getDynamicCastFunction() const
        { return m_dynamicCastFunction; }

    //! Return slot function applying a static cast on the message pointer
    Function getStaticCastFunction() const
        { return m_staticCastFunction; }

    //! Operator () using the dynamic cast
    void operator()(Message::Ptr msg, Link * link = nullptr )
        { m_dynamicCastFunction( msg, link); }

protected:

    //! Construct Slot by derived class instance construction only
    Slot( const TypeDef& type, Function dynamicCastFunction,
          Function staticCastFunction ) :
        m_msgType(type),
        m_dynamicCastFunction(dynamicCastFunction),
        m_staticCastFunction(staticCastFunction)
    {
    }

    //! Insert link in set
    void connect( Link* link )
        { m_links.insert( link ); }

    //! Remove link from set
    void disconnect( Link* link )
        { m_links.erase( link ); }

    //! Set of active links
    LinkSet m_links;

    //! Type of accepted messages
    const TypeDef& m_msgType;

    //! Slot method usind dynamic cast on message pointer
    const Function m_dynamicCastFunction;

    //! Slot method using static cast on message pointer
    const Function m_staticCastFunction;
};


template <class TObj, class TMsg, 
          void (TObj::*TMethod)(typename TMsg::Ptr, Link*)>
class SlotT : public Slot
{
public:

    //! SlotT constructor with templated type
    SlotT( TObj* obj )
        : Slot(TMsg::Type(),
          std::bind( &SlotT<TObj,TMsg,TMethod>::dynamicCastFunction, obj,
                                      std::placeholders::_1,
                                      std::placeholders::_2 ),
          std::bind( &SlotT<TObj,TMsg,TMethod>::staticCastFunction, obj,
                                           std::placeholders::_1,
                                           std::placeholders::_2 ) )
    {
    }

private:
    //! dynamic cast function
    static void dynamicCastFunction( TObj* obj, 
                                     typename Message::Ptr msg, 
                                     Link* link )
    {
        typename TMsg::Ptr m = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<TMsg>(msg);
        if( m && obj )
            (obj->*TMethod)(m, link);
    }

    //! static cast function
    static void staticCastFunction( TObj* obj, 
                                    typename Message::Ptr msg, 
                                    Link* link )
    {
        typename TMsg::Ptr m = std::static_pointer_cast<TMsg>(msg);
        if( m && obj )
            (obj->*TMethod)(m, link);
    }    
};
```